# Как правильно работать с ивентами в группе элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как правильно цеплять ивенты к группе элементов, чтобы скрипт работал с каждым элементов в отдельности?

Т.е. есть, например, сетка элементов из новостей, у которых есть заголовок и картинка (ее в коде нет). Я хочу, чтобы при клике на заголовок выезжало описание новости.

Реализовать то я реализовал, но не уверен что это верный путь для решения задачи.

```js
$('.item .button').click(function(){
 $(this).parents('.item').find(".text").toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.item{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background:#f00;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.button{
  background:#0f0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.text{
  background:#0ff;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  transition:top 1s;
}
.text.active{
   top:20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="item"><div class='button'>click</div><div class='text'>text</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class='button'>click</div><div class='text'>text</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class='button'>click</div><div class='text'>text</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class='button'>click</div><div class='text'>text</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('.item').find(".text").toggleClass('active');
```

`parents` собирает все элементы из цепочки родителей, удовлетворяющие селектору.

`closest` же находит максимум один элемент - что требуется в данном случае и семантически соответствует смыслу Вашего кода.

https://api.jquery.com/parents/

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: А разница?  Смысл тот же. По мне - это корявенько выглядит, неужели нельзя по другому?

Comment: @Pavel вам шашечки или ехать?

Comment: @Pavel Это не "корявенько", а именно так, как Вам надо. `parents` собирает все элементы из цепочки родителей, удовлетворяющие селектору. `closest` же находит максимум один элемент - что требуется в данном случае и семантически соответствует смыслу этого кода.

Comment: @Igor я думал в целом есть иной путь, но судя по ответам - нет. Спасибо за поправку :)

Comment: @Pavel а как вам моя реализация?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин я отметил ее стрелочкой ) Хорошо что ближе к js, но она несколько больше чем на jq и не выглядит элегантной. Но гуд что без jq

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).next(".text").toggleClass('active');
или
$(this).next().toggleClass('active');
или
$(this).siblings(".text").toggleClass('active');
или
$(this).siblings().toggleClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Я задаю класс `active` родителю в JavaScript и всё, а в css элементам-детям можно менять свойства просто через `item.active имя_элемента`

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let button = items[i].querySelector('.button');
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        items[i].classList.toggle('active');
    });
}
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}

.item{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background:#f00;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button{
  background:#0f0;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.text{
  background:#0ff;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  transition:top 1s;
}

.item.active .text{
   top:20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="item">
  <div class='button'>click</div>
  <div class='text'>text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class='button'>click</div>
  <div class='text'>text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class='button'>click</div>
  <div class='text'>text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class='button'>click</div>
  <div class='text'>text</div>
 </div>
</div>
```